# What's difference between boost.asio and the packet unp.h in unpv?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, unix-socket

As what I've mentioned above, what's difference between them? The latter can be used on unix, as does boost.asio.

Comment: By "unp" do you mean the book Unix Network Programming, and the helper functions for the low-level system calls it provides?

Comment: yeah, for example, #include <unp.h>

Comment: The main difference is that one is a generic C++ framework for communication, and the other is just simple low-level C functions wrapping even lower-level functions.. So in short they are really not the same at all, and it would be easier to answer what similarities they have (which there are few, if any).